# How can I add extra space in between lines in Algorithm if superscript and subscripts close to each other?

Tags: algorithms

When upper line has `subscripts` and lower line has `superscripts` they may end up pretty close to each other in Algorithm.

Is it possible to put extra space in between lines in Algorithm if lines are end up so close to each other?

I have following code:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The sadWorld Function}
    \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Input:} {}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State{}{$j{.}Z_{H_{d_i}}^{\mathrm{pr}} \gets 0 $}
        \State{}$p_n{.}\Pi^{\mathrm{p}}[H_{d_i}] \gets 0$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

its output:

[image]

Here when you look closely `$d_i$` and `p` is pretty close to each other hence `i` could be seen as superscript of `p`. Is it possible to add extra space in between them (Line 1 and 2)? If possible handle this operation automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a bit of vspace:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{The sadWorld Function}
    \hspace*{\algorithmicindent} \textbf{Input:} {}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State{}{$j{.}Z_{H_{d_i}}^{\mathrm{pr}} \gets 0 $}
        \vspace*{3mm}
        \State{}$p_n{.}\Pi^{\mathrm{p}}[H_{d_i}] \gets 0$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be automatically handled?

Comment: @alper not really, but that is not a problem of `algorithmicx`, also in regular paragraphs with inline math this is a problem that is not resolved automatically. Maybe try to avoid triple subscripts :) and check carefully the output of each algorithm environment.

Comment: I will triple subscripts :) What do you mean by `output of each algorithm environment` ?

Comment: I meant to make sure when you compile your document that you look carefully at the algorithms in the pdf to see if they contain lines that are too close together.